# Find method not recognized in Entity Framework "Database-First" class

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I am doing a simple edit in ASP.NET MVC. The action result code is below. This [example here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg685489) 
says I can do the following.

Code example:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
   {
       using (var db = new BlogDataEntities())
       {
           return View(db.Blogs.Find(id));
       }
    }
```

But when I try to do it, I cannot get Find property for `db.Amodel.`?
What am I missing?

My code:

```
public ActionResult Edit(string id)
    {
        using (var db = new dbAEntities())
        {
           return View(db.Amodel.Find(id));//This is not working. Find is not     
                                           //recognzied and intellisense does 
                                           //not give me that option too.
        }           
    }
```

Comment: Looks like `Amodel` doesn't have a `Find()` method.

Comment: Isnt the find method automatically created .. the example in the link I provided, does not talk about writing own Find method.. using the method in the link, all the methods necessary like Add, Find should be created automatically .. isnt it?

Comment: What type is `Amodel`?  Does it have similar characteristics to `Blogs`, i.e. was it created using Database First?

Comment: EntityObject ... Yes.I am following the sample, even though my database fields and name are different I am also using Database first.. lot of the code in the background is automatically generated.. when I created the models automatically by picking ADO.NET Entity Data Model option...

Comment: Create functionality worked well.. without any issues.. I followed the same sample ..

Comment: I guess you'll have to figure out how `Amodel` differs from `Blogs`, because `Blogs` clearly has a `Find()` method, while `Amodel` does not.

Comment: @RobertHarvey  Thanks for helping. Wiktors suggestion was spot on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are referring to the Entity Framework 4.1 which seems to introduce the `Find` method. You are probably using an older version. Rewrite the code to:

```
public ActionResult Edit(string id)     
{         
   using (var db = new dbAEntities()) {
        return View(db.Amodel.FirstOrDefault(item => item.id == id));
   }
}
```

Comment: I was guessing something like this was happening.. thanks for pointing out. This worked.

Comment: SingleOrDefault is probably more appropriate. Since Find is looking at the key properties, there should only be a single entity with the same key(s).

Comment: @ZVenue That example is with entity framework 4.1 if you want to use 4.1 download it via package manager http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ee712906

Comment: Also I am in the same boat with this line of code in the sample.... db.Entry(blog).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified; cant seem to make it work in my copy..